# Apple safari is crashing again and again

Tags: safari, macos, crash

My Safari browser is crashing again and again while I am working , this is the error that It prompts to send to apple overtime it crashes.

```
Process:               com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service [773]
Path:                  /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariSafeBrowsing.framework/Versions/A/com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service
Identifier:            com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service
Version:               7602.1.50
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service [773]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-12-16 22:38:57.112 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.12 (16A323)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        A975CB81-1635-0611-4AD9-0DC61C4EC9A0


Time Awake Since Boot: 490 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        3  Dispatch queue: com.apple.SafeBrowsing.Backend.Google.DatabaseUpdater

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000107b03000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0x107b03000:
    mapped file            0000000107828000-0000000107b03000 [ 2924K] r--/r-x SM=PRV  
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010ba58000-000000010ba96000 [  248K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld

Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffb84b2ff6 __semwait_signal_nocancel + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffb83c0944 nanosleep$NOCANCEL + 188
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fffb83e7f43 sleep$NOCANCEL + 42
3   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb835c2d6 _dispatch_queue_cleanup2 + 113
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859c51f _pthread_tsd_cleanup + 544
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859c259 _pthread_exit + 152
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859cdb8 pthread_exit + 30
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb835c23d dispatch_main + 77
8   com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing   0x00007fffb41d82dc SafeBrowsing::Service::main() + 150
9   com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service   0x000000010499bf96 0x10499b000 + 3990
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fffb8384255 start + 1

Thread 1:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos.overcommit
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffb84b327e __sigsuspend_nocancel + 10
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb835c34c _dispatch_sigsuspend + 21
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb835c337 _dispatch_sig_thread + 41

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffb84b34e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a7c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 3 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.SafeBrowsing.Backend.Google.DatabaseUpdater
0   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fffb85900ba _platform_memmove$VARIANT$Nehalem + 90
1   libcommonCrypto.dylib           0x00007fffb82b2161 ccdigest_process + 135
2   libcommonCrypto.dylib           0x00007fffb82b20ca CC_SHA256_Update + 88
3   com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing   0x00007fffb41deecf Backend::Google::DatabaseUpdater::verifyDatabaseChecksum(Backend::Google::DatabaseInfo const&, std::__1::array<unsigned char, 32ul> const&) + 123
4   com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing   0x00007fffb41de654 Backend::Google::DatabaseUpdater::writeUpdatedDatabase(Backend::Google::DatabaseInfo&, Backend::Google::ListUpdateResponse const&, std::__1::chrono::time_point<std::__1::chrono::system_clock, std::__1::chrono::duration<long long, std::__1::ratio<1l, 1000000l> > >) + 968
5   com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing   0x00007fffb41ddf86 Backend::Google::DatabaseUpdater::didFetchEncodedUpdates(NSData*, NSHTTPURLResponse*, NSError*) + 400
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb8356f5f _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb834e128 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb8364b97 _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 896
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb8356d41 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1046
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb834fee0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 476
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00007fffb834fcb7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 99
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a746 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffb84b34e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a632 _pthread_wqthread + 1023
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffb84b34e6 __workq_kernreturn + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a7c5 _pthread_wqthread + 1426
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a221 start_wqthread + 13

Thread 6:: com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffb84ab41a mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fffb84aa867 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa32b3ba4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa32b3021 __CFRunLoopRun + 1361
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fffa32b2874 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
5   com.apple.CFNetwork             0x00007fffa2487144 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 313
6   com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fffa4cdf30d __NSThread__start__ + 1243
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859aabb _pthread_body + 180
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859aa07 _pthread_start + 286
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fffb859a231 thread_start + 13

Thread 3 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000070000ab7525d  rbx: 0x0000000000000005  rcx: 0x00007fffc1032100  rdx: 0x0000000000000001
  rdi: 0x000070000ab75261  rsi: 0x0000000107b03000  rbp: 0x000070000ab75150  rsp: 0x000070000ab75150
   r8: 0x0000000000000005   r9: 0x0000000107b02ffc  r10: 0x000070000ab75268  r11: 0x00006fff03072261
  r12: 0x00007fffc1032188  r13: 0x0000000000000005  r14: 0x0000000107b02ffc  r15: 0x0000000000000035
  rip: 0x00007fffb85900ba  rfl: 0x0000000000010202  cr2: 0x0000000107b03000

Logical CPU:     1
Error Code:      0x00000004
Trap Number:     14


Binary Images:
       0x10499b000 -        0x10499bfff  com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service (7602.1.50) <8438A8F3-78B7-381F-9E66-D491AD45FA3D> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariSafeBrowsing.framework/com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service
       0x10ba58000 -        0x10ba951c7  dyld (421.1) <A525EAEA-AF86-30C2-B360-3D093B4F0828> /usr/lib/dyld
    0x7fff9fdc7000 -     0x7fff9fdc7fff  com.apple.Accelerate (1.11 - Accelerate 1.11) <BDDB2053-BB24-34E4-A452-50D1260BF672> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Accelerate
    0x7fff9fde0000 -     0x7fffa0420fe3  com.apple.vImage (8.1 - ???) <6CC22156-EC5C-3DC3-8132-41376F090B08> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vImage.framework/Versions/A/vImage
    0x7fffa0421000 -     0x7fffa05e8fef  libBLAS.dylib (1185) <0D55CF73-6DBD-3D15-B500-189479638551> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
    0x7fffa05e9000 -     0x7fffa0600fff  libBNNS.dylib (14) <43A9B06E-3C21-3CE6-B0C1-99DA172DEEB0> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBNNS.dylib
    0x7fffa0601000 -     0x7fffa0a0cfff  libLAPACK.dylib (1185) <E7AE9C48-6E42-3EB7-A257-D48E0CB48D00> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
    0x7fffa0a0d000 -     0x7fffa0a23fff  libLinearAlgebra.dylib (1185) <08F00EFB-B477-3421-906E-3D364E607E6A> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLinearAlgebra.dylib
    0x7fffa0a24000 -     0x7fffa0a2afff  libQuadrature.dylib (3) <120F6228-A3D4-3184-89D7-785ADC2AC715> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libQuadrature.dylib
    0x7fffa0a2b000 -     0x7fffa0a3eff7  libSparseBLAS.dylib (1185) <912E3D25-27C0-3245-B64C-3CAD43A5D633> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libSparseBLAS.dylib

    0x7fffb85d7000 -     0x7fffb8600ff7  libxpc.dylib (972.1.5) <2A901937-48E1-3BF2-83F1-2431156D82B7> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 376
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=190.7M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=190.7M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=56.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=56.4M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Activity Tracing                   256K        2 
Dispatch continuations            8192K        2 
Kernel Alloc Once                    8K        2 
MALLOC                            36.9M       13 
MALLOC guard page                   16K        4 
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        8 
Stack                             11.0M        8 
VM_ALLOCATE                          4K        2 
__DATA                            9184K      137 
__LINKEDIT                       111.3M        4 
__TEXT                            79.4M      140 
__UNICODE                          556K        2 
mapped file                       38.5M        7 
shared memory                       48K        5 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                            351.0M      322 

Model: MacBookPro9,2, BootROM MBP91.00D3.B0D, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.5 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 2.2f38
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424455302D474E2D4620
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3230554638424455302D474E2D4620
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xF5), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.171.10.1a16)
Bluetooth: Version 5.0.0f18, 3 services, 17 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS547550A9E384, 500.11 GB
Serial ATA Device: HL-DT-ST DVDRW  GS31N
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: IR Receiver
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 25.1
```

Answer (score 4):

MacWorld has an article about this. There is no official fix but a workaround is described, and that is to use the private viewing window on a Mac, or turn off suggestions on an iPhone or iPad.

http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/help-safari-keeps-crashing-ios-iphone-ipad-mac-ios-93-bug-3601623/

Also, on an Apple discussion thread, someone suggested temporarily moving the com.apple.Safari.plist file and seeing if that helps.

Close down Safari, then open Terminal:

Go to your Library/Safari folder:

```
cd ~/Library/Safari/
```

List all files, including hidden files:

```
ls -la
```

If you see a file for com.apple.safari.plist, back it up:

```
mv com.apple.safari.plist com.apple.safari.plist.bak
```

Try running Safari. If the problem continues or you have other problems, it didn't work. Go back into Terminal and put the original file back:

```
rm com.apple.safari.plist
mv com.apple.safari.plist.bak com.apple.safari.plist
```

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7705708?start=0&tstart=0

I personally have not experienced a problem with this, as I only use Chrome, so I hope this helps.

Comment: Had the same issue: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7412260?start=0&tstart=0 solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I clean my system junk all safari database with cleanmymac 3 and now look like good! No crash popup window. yep I hope

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best. Explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve this problem by deleting these three cached Google files:

```
com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing/Google/malware,osx,url_expression
com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing/Google/social_engineering,osx,url_expression
com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing/Google/unwanted_software,osx,url_expression
```

The files are located in a private folder with a cryptic name. To find it, start with the Finder command:

> Go -> Go to Folder...  `/private/var/folders`

[image]

The folders within the `folders` folder correspond to different user accounts. Your folder is the only one that lets you navigate into the **C** subfolder.

Within the **C** folder, navigate to `./com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing/Google`:

[image]

Move the three files in the Google folder to the trash. After restarting Safari, the files will automatically regenerate in a few minutes. This stopped the crashing!